# Unable to get key defined

Tags: javascript

Suppose response is `{"errmsg":"Error_BB"}` or `{"msg":"I am BB"}`.

```
var jsonparsed = JSON.parse(response);// OK, It works

var key = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(jsonparsed);// key can be msg or errmsg, OK, It works

if("errmsg" == key)
    {
        throw ("Error says:"+jsonparsed.key); //It cannot work but if jsonparsed.errmsg, it works 
    }
else
    {
        alert("Data says:"+jsonparsed.key); //It cannot work but if  jsonparsed. msg, it works
    }
```

I get this alert:

> The error says  that value is undefined

Why is that since the key seems defined as the comparison condition can be determined.

I am not able to throw or produce alert msg. However, if key is replaced with errmsg or msg as shown in the comments it works.

Comment: What is the exact content of key? Isn't this supposed to be an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `jsonparsed` doesn't have a property `key`, does it? It either has `errmsg` or `msg`, as you said. So it's not surprising that `jsonparsed.key` is `undefined`.

If you want to access a property whose name is contained in a variable, you have to use **bracket notation**:

```
obj[prop]
```

But there is more: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` returns an **array** of property names. While `"errmsg" == key` might work because of implicit type coercion, you really want to get the first element of the array:

```
var key = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(jsonparsed)[0]; // get first element

if("errmsg" === key) {
    throw ("Error says:"+jsonparsed[key]);
}
else {
    alert("Data says:"+jsonparsed[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the expression `jsonparsed.key` you are asking for a property named `"key"` at the `jsonparsed` object.

To retrieve the key whose name is a var value, you can use the array-like notation:

```
throw ("Error says:"+jsonparsed[key]);
```

or use the eval function:

```
throw ("Error says:"+eval("jsonparsed."+key));
```